# collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAt not called swift 4 iOS 11

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios11, swift4

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    }
}

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setup() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

`numberOfSections` and `numberOfItemsInSection` are called (according to breakpoint), but `cellForItemAt` and `sizeForItemAt` are never called.

I don't see anything wrong?

UPDATE: (How I create HomeController in AppDelegate)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    let homeController = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)

    return true
}
```

Comment: are you making collection view programmatically?If not remove the line -: collectionView?.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId), and use provided identifier from storyboard

Comment: I am doing it programmatically. No storyboard.

Comment: @VanDuTran  Are you using XIB? no then how you created instance of `HomeController`

Comment: @Jack I updated my post with more code. I am not using XIB. It's all programatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `UICollectionViewLayout()`

You should [use](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html) -

```
 let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```